# How to set origin header to websocket client in Rust?

Tags: rust, websocket, tauri

How to add origin to websocket client "connect_async" in backend Tauri?

Just like in JavaScript, it is easy to set the origin in the websocket backend:

```js
    const ws = new WebSocket(
      "wss://server.example.com", 
      { origin: "https://example.com" }
    );
```

And how do you add an Origin header to the client in Rust in the Tauri backend?
I'm using the library tokio-tungstenite.

```rust
  let (mut ws_remote, _) = connect_async(
    Url::parse("wss://server.example.com").expect("Can't connect to URL"),
).await?;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `http::Request` instead of just a `Url`:

```
use http::Request;
use tokio_tungstenite;

let request = Request::builder()
    .uri("wss://server.example.com")
    .header("Origin", "https://example.com")
    .body(())?;

let (mut ws_remote, _) = tokio_tungstenite::connect_async(request).await?;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I corrected a little and it works now. Added Method.

Answer (score 4):

You can let tungstenite build the request for you via `into_client_request()`:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use tokio_tungstenite::{connect_async, tungstenite::client::IntoClientRequest};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut request = "wss://server.example.com".into_client_request()?;
    let headers = request.headers_mut();
    headers.insert("Origin", "https://example.com".parse().unwrap());
    let (socket_stream) = connect_async(request).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

So there is no need to manually generate a key or specify the websocket version.

Answer (score 1):

@isaactfa Thank you for answer, I corrected a little and it works now.

```rust
  let request = Request::builder()
    .method("GET")
    .header("Host", "wss://example.com")
    .header("Origin", "https://example.com/")
    .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
    .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key())
    .uri("wss://example.com")
    .body(())?;
  let (mut ws_remote, _) = connect_async(request).await?;
```