# Rust Tokio to Django Channels 4 `sec-websocket-key` error

Tags: rust, websocket, django-channels, rust-tokio

I've written a websocket client in Rust, using `tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::http::Request` to establish a connection, and running a Django Channels 4 server on an ASGI/Daphne version 4.0.0 development server.

When I use a current version of `tokio` (specifically 0.20), I get the following error:

```
Protocol(InvalidHeader("sec-websocket-key"))
```

However, when I downgrade `tokio` to 0.14, the client code runs without issues and the websocket connection is established and functions as expected. (note that I haven't tried other versions inbetween - it just so happens that I had previously gotten it to work on 0.14, and just wanted to upgrade to the most recent version for this project, which happens to be 0.20)

After a bit of reading, I understand that the key is part of the handshake that establishes the websocket connection. However, it also appears that the `tungstenite` connector should be able to automatically generate this, and I shouldn't be expected to set this myself in my headers.

These lines are probably most relevant:

```
    let request = Request::builder()
        .uri(&uri)
        .header("Origin", origin)
        .body(()).unwrap();

    let res = connect_async(request).await;
    match res {
       Ok((ws_stream, _)) => {
       ...
```

Please disregard the unwrapping - this is not production code, I'm interested in solving the technical issues before making things nicer.

Should I in fact generate a key, and set it in the headers? Is there a way to get `tungstenite` to do that for me in concert while I still want to set an `Origin` header? Or am I missing the bigger picture here?

After reading [How to set origin header to websocket client in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317229/how-to-set-origin-header-to-websocket-client-in-rust) I tried the following:

```
    let request = Request::builder()
        .uri(&uri)
        .header("Host", host)
        .header("Origin", origin)
        .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
        .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key())
        .body(()).unwrap();
```

But this results in another error which suggests that the server is not happy with the attempt:

```
Http(Response { status: 400, version: HTTP/1.1, headers: {}, body: Some([]) })
```

And if I downgrade back to 0.14, the code won't even work, as `generate_key()` is private in that version, so it seems that `tungstenite` doesn't expect me to call it myself (or at least didn't used to).

What may `tokio 0.14` be doing that `0.20` does not, and how should I resolve this?

Comment: Looking through the source, it does appear (in tungstenite 0.20) that if you want to provide your own `Request` then you must provide those headers. But your request looks like it should work, are you sure you have the `host` correct?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it closely. You were right, there was a mistake in the port number for `host`, which corrected the issue. I suppose I should have a look at the source myself though. It seems odd that in a previous version tungstenite was able to derive these header fields, and now you have to specify them explicitly, even though I'm just deriving them from the uri (after resolving the issue). If you write a brief answer, I may add to that if I find anything, Otherwise I may write an answer I'll accept myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @kmdreko looked more closely and found that the likely culprit was the `"Host"` header field, which it was. The field was being passed ***without the port number***.

However, although the following works, with a correct value for `host`:

```rust
let request = Request::builder()
    .uri(&uri)
    .header("Host", host)
    .header("Origin", origin)
    .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
    .header("Upgrade", "websocket")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Version", "13")
    .header("Sec-WebSocket-Key", tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::handshake::client::generate_key())
    .body(()).unwrap();
```

This is a bit unsatisfying, since all these values are somewhat arbitrary and I wanted to leave it up to `tungstenite` to provide sensible defaults.

This did not work:

```rust
let request = Request::builder()
    .uri(&uri)
    .header("Origin", origin)
    .body(()).unwrap();
```

However, this is the solution I was looking for:

```rust
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::http::HeaderValue;
use tokio_tungstenite::tungstenite::client::IntoClientRequest;

// ..

let mut request = uri.into_client_request().unwrap();
let origin: HeaderValue = origin.parse().unwrap();
request.headers_mut()
    .insert("Origin", origin);
```

By defining `request` as mutable and then inserting the needed `"Origin"` field on the `Request` generated by `tungstenite`, I was able to get a working solution where `tungstenite` sets all the other fields to their required default/current settings.